# Pygame Collision | Why do I slide up walls in my tile based game?

Tags: collision-detection, tilemap, collision-resolution, pygame, tiled

My player if in contact with a wall either left/right/top(head) they will be able to just continue in the Y direction if you press jump as if you were flying. This is for all walls and invisible walls that work as boundaries on the side of the stage, if you're touch it on your left or right side you can press up and move up it.

```
def wall_collision(sprite, group, dir):
    if dir == 'x':
        collide = py.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
        if collide:
            if collide[0].rect.centerx > sprite.hit_rect.centerx:
                sprite.pos.x = collide[0].rect.left - sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
            if collide[0].rect.centerx < sprite.hit_rect.centerx:
                sprite.pos.x = collide[0].rect.right + sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
            sprite.vel.x = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centerx = sprite.pos.x
    if dir == 'y':
        collide = py.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
        if collide:
            if collide[0].rect.centery > sprite.hit_rect.centery:
                sprite.pos.y = collide[0].rect.top - sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            if collide[0].rect.centery < sprite.hit_rect.centery:
                sprite.pos.y = collide[0].rect.bottom + sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            sprite.vel.y = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centery = sprite.pos.y
```

This is the collision code and below is the update for the player:

```
def update(self):

self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.center = self.pos
self.pos += self.vel
self.hit_rect.centerx = self.pos.x
wall_collision(self, self.game.walls, 'x')
self.hit_rect.centery = self.pos.y
wall_collision(self, self.game.walls, 'y')
self.rect.center = self.hit_rect.center

# Apply Friction
self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
# Equation of motion
self.vel += self.acc
self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
```

def jump(self):

```
self.rect.x += 1
collision = py.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
self.rect.x -= 1
if collision:
    self.vel.y = -10
```

If you jump and your head touches a wall and you keep hold of the up arrow it keeps adding to your vel.y even though the wall is blocking you.

Comment: The behaviour you describe looks like exactly the behaviour you've asked for in your jump function. You check if the player is colliding with a wall, and if they are, you set their vertical velocity upward. You never check if they're standing on the ground, or if they've already used-up their jump and need to wait to return to the ground to jump again, or if they have room above their head to keep moving. Did you mean to include more code here that we can't see currently?

Comment: No but thanks anyways your comment was useful I just scraped the project

Comment: Want to delete your question then, or is there something else we can help you with?

Comment: How can I specify which wall the player is colliding with I just want it to just when touching the top of a wall as in their feet are on the ground

Comment: This is called a "ground check", and you can find [existing documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=pygame+ground+check) and [Q&A about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19386100/3064164)

Comment: Thank you Ill look into that